# How i can create Generic Method in Java?

Tags: java

I have two a conditions in the method:

```java
if(urlSendModel.isHasPhoto()) {
    ArrayList<InputMediaPhoto> inputMediaPhotos = new ArrayList<>();

    for(String photoUrl : urlSendModel.getPhotos()){
        inputMediaPhotos.add(new InputMediaPhoto(photoUrl));
    }

    SendMediaGroup sendMediaGroup = new SendMediaGroup(message.chat().id(),
            inputMediaPhotos.toArray(new InputMediaPhoto[0]));

    bot.execute(sendMediaGroup);
}
if(urlSendModel.isHasVideo()){
    ArrayList<InputMediaVideo> inputMediaVideos = new ArrayList<>();

    for(String videoUrl : urlSendModel.getVideos()){
        inputMediaVideos.add(new InputMediaVideo(videoUrl));
    }

    SendMediaGroup sendMediaGroup = new SendMediaGroup(message.chat().id(),
            inputMediaVideos.toArray(new InputMediaVideo[0]));

    bot.execute(sendMediaGroup);
}
```

How can I create something like this or solve the problem in another way.

```java
private <T extends InputMedia<T>> void sendMedia(Message message, ArrayList<String> urls) {
    ArrayList<T> inputMedia = new ArrayList<>();

    for(String url : urls){
        inputMedia.add(new T(url));
    }

    SendMediaGroup sendMediaGroup = new SendMediaGroup(message.chat().id(),
        inputMedia.toArray(new T[0]));

    bot.execute(sendMediaGroup);
}
```

I will be glad to any proposed solution.

Comment: You can get around `new T` by having the client specify a class literal, then calling `getConstructor(...).newInstance(...)`. But this will not work for creating a generic array. You'd have to pass the responsibility of creating these objects to the client: `sendMedia(message, urls, InputMediaVideo::new, () -> new InputMediaVideo[0]);`, declaring the method as `<T extends InputMedia<T>> void sendMedia(Message, Function<String, T>, Supplier<T[]>)`

Comment: @VinceEmigh: You can also use `Array.newInstance(klass, length);` (and pass in the `class`) which might be more understandable when reading.

Comment: @BeUndead Nice. Deleted my answer because I believe what you suggested would be the proper/easiest way. Haven't looked into reflection for a while, so I must have overlooked that. Feel free to write an answer, will get an upvote from me.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the requirements here can be gotten around by passing the `class` into the method.  I'll skip the additional details of what your method does, but, for instance:

```java
<T> void doSomething(final Class<T> klass, final int length) {
    // Replace 'new T[10]'
    final T[] array = Array.newInstance(klass, length);

    final Constructor<T> constructor = klass.getConstructor();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        // Replace 'new T()'
        array[i] = constructor.newInstance();
    }
}
```

---

- Note 1: The replacement for `new T()` was provided by [@Vince Emigh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2398375/vince-emigh).
- Note 2: `Exception` handling is not considered here, so this will not compile as-is.
- Note 3: If you need to use a *different* constructor to the one with no arguments, then it may well be simpler to accept a `Function<Object[], T>` which will convert the arguments you provide to an instance of the type.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like creating the generic class first :

```
public class ClassList<T extends Object>{ private ArrayList<T> list; .... }
// or
public class ClassList<T extends InputMedia>{ private ArrayList<T> list; .... }
```

and then you cas use constructor or setter to affect a value to your attribute list of T